# Data not showing on Silverlight controls in datagrid after setting itemsource

Tags: silverlight, binding, datagrid

I have been searching for a while, and nothing I have tried has resolved the issue.  The below code executes without errors, but no data shows in the template.

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="GOReviewSL.UserControls.Announcements"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="75" d:DesignWidth="280" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Local;assembly=Local">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <my:Fieldset Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="fieldset1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
            <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="AnnouncementsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="AnnouncmentTitleLink" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Title}" Click="AnnouncmentTitleLink_Click" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorText" Text="{Binding Author}" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="AnnouncementText" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </my:Fieldset>
    <Image Source="/GOReviewSL;component/Images/announcements.png" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="20,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

The Announcement class:

```
    public class Announcement
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public Announcement()
    {
        this.Author = string.Empty;
        this.Title = string.Empty;
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.ModifiedDate = string.Empty;
    }

    public Announcement(string author, string title, string text, string modifiedDate)
    {
        this.Author = author;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Text = text;
        this.ModifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }
}
```

My binding code:

```
        public Announcements()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objController.ListAnnouncementsCompleted += new EventHandler<ListAnnouncementsCompletedEventArgs>(objController_ListAnnouncementsCompleted);
        objController.ListAnnouncementsAsync();
    }

    void objController_ListAnnouncementsCompleted(object sender, ListAnnouncementsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var objAnnouncements = from el in e.Result
                               select el;

        AnnouncementsGrid.DataContext = objAnnouncements.ToList();
        AnnouncementsGrid.ItemsSource = objAnnouncements.ToList();
    }
```

I've changed up that last bit several times.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I got this problem too, only show blank in the grid, although the row.count is right.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind your `Grid` to `ObservableCollection`. First I was using List and had many problems while loading the DataGrid. It is advised to use `ObservableCollection` in Silverlight instead of `List`. [Why to use ObservableCollection instead of List in Silverlight](http://mscoder.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/why-to-use-observablecollection-instead-of-list-in-silverlight/)

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    ObservableCollection<Announcement> announcementCollection;

            public ObservableCollection<Announcement> AnnouncementCollection
            {
                get { return announcementCollection; }
                set
                {
                    announcementCollection = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("AnnouncementCollection");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was very helpful.  The data was there, but not showing.  This helped to resolve that.  Thank you as both yours and the comment below helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work, although there is a bit of redundant calls in there:

```
// This is not necessary, and neither is ItemsSource="{Binding}"
//AnnouncementsGrid.DataContext = objAnnouncements.ToList();
AnnouncementsGrid.ItemsSource = objAnnouncements.ToList();
```

You should check that objAnnouncements.ToList() actually has values. Set a breakpoint on it.

Things to check:

1. I wonder if your image is covering up the grid. Try commenting it out first.
2. I don't know what FieldSet is. Does the Datagrid work when it is outside the fieldset?

Comment: Part of it was being covered up.  The fieldset helped to hide that. I was able to remove the fieldset to find it and add it back later after adjusting the position. (The fieldset is an object that acts like an HTML fieldset).  Thank you as both yours and the comment above helped to resolve the issue.